# How to optimize Makefile

Tags: makefile

I write a ugly copy/paste way created `Makefile`:

```
all: download install

install: \
    ${EXTERNAL_MODELS_LOCAL}/squeezenet_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5 \
    ${EXTERNAL_MODELS_LOCAL}/resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5 \
    ${EXTERNAL_MODELS_LOCAL}/inception_v3_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5 \

${EXTERNAL_MODELS_LOCAL}/squeezenet_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5:
    ln -s ${EXTERNAL_MODELS_ROOT}/squeezenet_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5 $@

${EXTERNAL_MODELS_LOCAL}/resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5:
    ln -s ${EXTERNAL_MODELS_ROOT}/resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5 $@

${EXTERNAL_MODELS_LOCAL}/inception_v3_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5:
    ln -s ${EXTERNAL_MODELS_ROOT}/inception_v3_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5 $@

download: $(EXTERNAL_MODELS_ROOT)/ \
    $(EXTERNAL_MODELS_ROOT)/squeezenet_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5 \
    $(EXTERNAL_MODELS_ROOT)/resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5 \
    $(EXTERNAL_MODELS_ROOT)/inception_v3_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5 \

$(EXTERNAL_MODELS_ROOT)/squeezenet_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5:
    wget https://github.com/OlafenwaMoses/ImageAI/releases/download/1.0/squeezenet_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5 \
    -O $@

$(EXTERNAL_MODELS_ROOT)/resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5:
    wget https://github.com/OlafenwaMoses/ImageAI/releases/download/1.0/resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5 \
    -O $@

$(EXTERNAL_MODELS_ROOT)/inception_v3_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5:
    wget https://github.com/OlafenwaMoses/ImageAI/releases/download/1.0/inception_v3_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5 \
    -O $@
```

Biggest part skipped ,but looks the same. Is it possible to optimize this boilerplate?

Comment: Optimize in what way? Space? Time? Lines of code? Reliability?

Comment: @l0b0 Lines of code and reliability as final result. I change it time to time and errors in copy/pasting occurs occasionally. I see common structure but can't understand how to fold it to some kind of `function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mixture of make variables, [make automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) (e.g. `$<`, `$@`), make functions (e.g. `addsuffix`, `addprefix`) and [pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules), maybe:

```
RHOST   := https://github.com/OlafenwaMoses/ImageAI/releases/download/1.0/
H5STEM  := squeezenet resnet50 inception_v3
H5      := $(addsuffix _weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5,$(H5STEM))
H5LOCAL := $(addprefix $(EXTERNAL_MODELS_LOCAL)/,$(H5))
H5ROOT  := $(addprefix $(EXTERNAL_MODELS_ROOT)/,$(H5))

.PHONY: install download

install: $(H5LOCAL)

download: $(H5ROOT)

$(EXTERNAL_MODELS_LOCAL)/%.h5: $(EXTERNAL_MODELS_ROOT)/%.h5
    ln -s $< $@

$(EXTERNAL_MODELS_ROOT)/%.h5:
    wget $(RHOST)/$*.h5 -O $@
```

And of course, if there was a way to automatically discover the list of remote `*.h5` files, it would be even better. But some more information is needed to imagine how to do it (`ssh`, `curl`, `wget`... ?). The make `shell` function would be the starting point, of course:

```
H5 := $(shell <the-command-that-lists-the-remote-h5-files>)
```

Comment: perfect, it's exactly what i want. thank you very much